# StringCollection vs. ObservableCollection<string>

Tags: c#, string, collections

I am currently trying to grasp the concepts of Collections in C#. I am working on an App that is based on WPF and MVVM. I want my ViewModel to have some sort of List or Collection of strings, which can make use of an "OnChangedEventHandler", such as the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler`. This would be provided by the `ObservableCollection` class. In contrast to the `ObservableCollection` class, the `StringCollection` class prvides a `Contains` method to determine whether the specified string is in the Collection.

What should I use if I want to have both the "Contains method" and the "OnChangedEventHandler"?

**UPDATE**

Solved by:

```
public class MyStringCollection : ObservableCollection<string>
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    // Check if MyStringCollection contains the specified string
    public bool Contains(string str)
    {
        return (strings.Any(c => (String.Compare(str, c) == 0)));
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ObservableCollection supports the Conatins method extension.

Just add the following using statement to your class:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I actually thought that the 'Contains' method of ObservableCollection uses the Equals on object, which simply checks whether the memory addresses are the same. However, I want to check whether the content of the string is the same.

Comment: You can extract a property from each element of the collection as a separate collection and use Contains on there as well.

Comment: var ids = MyCollection.Select(c => c.Id);

Comment: What's "c" and what's "Id"?

Comment: I gave you an example of a lambda expression. Let 'c' be an item within MyCollection and Id is just a made-up property in the class that the collection is using. So for each c object in MyCollection, select c.Id. This will return a list of id objects that could be strings if Ids are of type string.

Comment: Thank you for the explenation! I just updated my question. Would be so great if you could have a look at it.

Comment: It looks okay. You could also use the Any method extension to return a bool result from a LINQ expression. Please mark this thread as an answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the final solution in my question.